# Blender 3.0 Denoiser disappeared

Tags: denoise

I installed a new Blender 3.0, but there is no tool in the setting Denoiser. I have reinstalled several times new Blender 3.0 without changes. In Blender 2.9.3 and and earlier versions Denoiser works great. I understand my processor is very old, but maybe the problem is not with it.

[image]

[image]

Viewport Sampling Preset Error:

```
 Failed to execute the preset: TypeError('bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "OPENIMAGEDENOISE" not found in (\'AUTO\')')
```

My PC Info: CPU: AMD Athlon II X4 645 GPU: GTX 1050 RAM: 12GB Blender Version: 3.0.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect that Blender is not detecting your GPU and since you've selected GPU Compute, it does not show any denoiser. Either switch to CPU or resolve the GPU detection issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in Blender Preferences/System/CUDA my GPU detected. I tried changing in Render Properties/Scene/Device GPU to CPU, but nothing changed.

Comment: May be check and update your Nvidia and CUDA drivers.

Comment: Thanks, didn’t think about trying to update the video card drivers. I will change, I will write what happens!

Comment: I have installed the most recent drivers msi GeForce GTX 1050 win10-win11-64bit-Studio Driver 472.84 and it helped! Thanks for the help, Bruno!!!

Comment: glad it helped!