# Blender Denoise doesnt work

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

In the Denoise tab in the Render properties there is nothing to select, but I want to use the Denoiser. If I try to render an image with denoise on the result is a black Image. Blender Version 3.0

My System:

```
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965 3.4 GHz
GPU: AMD Radeon R9 380
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247331/blender-3-0-denoiser-disappeared

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)